# How to add CSS code for multiple color in one click on web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive-design

How to add a CSS which we can change. like if we change in one place, the color of the whole website should get changed.

Screenshot : [screenshot for Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCPFZ.png)

Sample website : https://themezhub.net/rikada-demo-05/rikada/index.html#

as you can see in above website, they have a slider in left side and which contain a list of color, if you choose any color the whole website color will change.

How to make like this?.

Example :

I define the color code in one place of CSS or website and then the whole website should get changed according to it.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class with the `body` tag on click left side colors. Then add CSS of color for each element that you'd like to update.

[how the change color works on reference site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oyCn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**"I define the color code in one place of CSS or website and then the whole website should get changed according to it."**

Above, is the best thought for such dynamic color for webpages.

Example code : -

```js
function change(color){
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass(color);
}
```

```css
body.black {
background-color : black;
color: white;
}

body.black .heading_1{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight : bold;
}

body.red {
background-color : red;
color: white;
}

body.red .heading_2{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight : bold;
}

body.green {
background-color : green;
color: white;
}

body.green .heading_3{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight : bold;
}

body.blue {
background-color : blue;
color: white;
}

body.blue .heading_4{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body class="black">
<span class="heading_1"> This is Black </span><br/>
<span class="heading_2"> This is Red </span><br/>
<span class="heading_3"> This is Green </span><br/>
<span class="heading_4"> This is Blue </span><br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="change('black')"> Black </button>
<button onclick="change('red')"> Red </button>
<button onclick="change('green')"> Green </button>
<button onclick="change('blue')"> Blue </button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can define any style to any of your element on page (`I have it on heading in my case`), also you can define any class for any of the element (`body.<class> in my case`) on page with respect to which you are going to change the style for other elements.